# How to include mutlitiple js files in angular app?

Tags: angularjs

I am creating app using angular js. I have many controllers. here is some of them

```
Controllers/AuthController.js
Controllers/UserController.js
Controllers/ContactController.js
Controllers/GroupController.js
Controllers/BaseController.js
```

and i also have services and models for each module. How can i include all these js files in angular app?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Grunt to merge and minify them. I suggest using [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) both as a scaffolding tool and an example to how to achieve what you want.

There's also a quite useful [tutorial](http://yeoman.io/codelab.html) to start.

Answer (score 2):

As well you can use angular with requireJS. Something like that http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs